# Understanding Scope and Lifetime of References in std::async within a Loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, stdasync

My question centers around the for-loop in the listDirs function, where I am launching async tasks. I am passing path by reference to `std::async` which then invokes the listDir function in a separate thread.

I am aware that once the for-loop moves to the next iteration, the path variable, which is a const reference to a `std::filesystem::path` instance in the paths vector, goes out of scope. However, listDir function's parameter is a reference which should be bound to path.

My understanding is that even though path goes out of scope in the listDirs function, the actual `std::filesystem::path` instances in the paths vector persist for the entire duration of the listDirs function, as we're passing by `std::ref`. But I'm not certain if this understanding is correct.

Can someone please clarify how this works? Specifically:

Does std::ref in `std::async` ensure that listDir gets a valid reference even when path goes out of scope in the listDirs function?
Is there any risk of a dangling reference in this scenario?

```
#include <filesystem>
using Iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator;
// The caller of this function is the thread runtime
std::vector<std::string> listDir(const std::filesystem::path& directory)
{
    
    
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    for (Iterator it(directory); it != Iterator(); ++it)
    {
        
        if (it->is_regular_file())
        {
            files.emplace_back(it->path().filename().string());
            
        }
        
    }
    // When we return this vector as the final action in the function, Return Value Optimization(RVO) takes place to
    // eliminate any extra copying of the vector
    return files;

}

std::vector<std::string> listDirs(const std::vector<std::filesystem::path>& paths)
{
    using Iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator;
    std::vector<std::future<std::vector<std::string>>> futures; // listDir returns std::vector<std::string> type
    // iterate over all the directory paths
    for (const std::filesystem::path& path : paths)
    {
    // start each thread using std::async
        futures.emplace_back(std::async(listDir, std::ref(path)));
    }
    std::vector<std::string> allFiles;
    for (std::future<std::vector<std::string>>& fut : futures)
    {

        std::vector<std::string> files = fut.get(); // RVO
        std::move(files.begin(), files.end(), std::back_inserter(allFiles));

    }
    // When we return this vector as the final action in the function, Return Value Optimization(RVO) takes place to
    // eliminate any extra copying of the vector
    return allFiles;
}
int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path currentPath("G:\\lesson4");
    std::vector<std::filesystem::path> paths;

    for (Iterator it(currentPath); it!= Iterator(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->is_directory())
        {
            std::cout << it->path() << '\n';
            paths.emplace_back(it->path());
        }
        
    }

    for (const auto& fileName : listDirs(paths))
    {
        std::cout << fileName << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: `path` doesn't really go "out of scope", since it's a reference to an element of `paths`. And _that_ is in scope for the entire `listDirs` function.

Comment: doesn't it even go out of scope at the end of each for-each iteration because it is temp variable and created at each iteration?

Comment: Concur with @paddy there, `path` is a ref to something else that continues to exist. I'm not even sure you need `std::ref(path)` here when adding to `futures`, though I could be wrong. Access to the `path` "symbol" itself *may* disappear at times but the thing it refers is "alive" at all times you're using it.

Comment: It's not a temporary variable. It's a _reference_. It refers literally to the thing that's inside your vector. If you pass that reference into something else, it's the _same_ reference.

Comment: By the way, @paddy, that should really be an *answer* rather than a comment.

Comment: @paddy Thanks for the explanations. My another question is does 'path' go out of scope at the end of each iteration and re-created with the same name?

Comment: Uhh, I don't know how many times I need to say _it's a reference_. It refers to a single element of your vector at any single loop iteration, since this is a range-based loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, the variable `path` is a [*reference*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). You can think of it a little like a pointer, except it's not.

```
for (const std::filesystem::path& path : paths)
{
    // start each thread using std::async
    futures.emplace_back(std::async(listDir, std::ref(path)));
}
```

At the first iteration of your loop, `path` refers to the first element of the vector `paths`. At the second iteration, it refers to the second element of the vector. And so on...

Because `paths` does not change for the lifetime of any reference into its elements (even those used in `futures`), this is safe. When you pass `path` into the `std::async` constructor with `std::ref(path)`, that reference wrapper will encapsulate the *current* reference.

In fact, [reference wrappers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) *are* typically implemented using a pointer under the hood, because that's the only practical way to pass around a reference as an *lvalue*.

Even if the loop moves to the second iteration before your first async method is called, the reference binding remains intact and *still* refers to the first element of `paths`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. It makes sense. why did you say 'You can think of it a little like a pointer, except it's not.' isn't a reference a const pointer?

Comment: No, a reference is a reference. Compilers can use pointers to implement references in some cases, but a reference is _not_ a pointer. To quote from the documentation linked to in my answer: a reference variable is _"an alias to an already-existing object or function"_. Also: _"References are not objects; they do not necessarily occupy storage"_. It's a subtle distinction, which is why I say you can think of them _like_ pointers, but it's important to avoid the trap of believing that they actually _are_ pointers... Because they are not. They are _references_. I hope I've now made this clear.

Comment: Yes. It is very clear. Thanks for your time and explanations. Appreciate it.